# When would pandas.get_dummies()'s parameter of drop_first=False be appropriate to use?

Tags: machine-learning, python, pandas, dummy-variables

While working on some case studies that use various machine learning models, I came across a project for predicting churn in the telecom industry. The Jupyter Notebook I saw had the following lines of code:

```
dummies1 = pd.get_dummies(df_churn, columns=cat_cols, drop_first=False) #for kNN and decision trees
dummies2 = pd.get_dummies(df_churn, columns=cat_cols, drop_first=True) #for logistic regression
```

As far as I knew, drop_first prevents the so-called 'Dummy Variable Trap'. Is there a reason for not dropping the extra dummy variable in the case of running kNN and Decision Tree models?

The Jupyter Notebook's author is unreachable, and I could not find the answers elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of `drop_first=True` is usually to avoid multicollinearity.

In one-hot encoding, you set 1 to the position associated to a discrete value among n possible options. When you one-hot encode a value, there is redundant information because you can figure out the value of any of the positions by computing 1 minus the sum of all other values. This means that any position of the one-hot encoded variable is a linear combination of the other positions.

This linear correlation, however, can be a problem in some cases. One example is when you want to know the effect the input features have on the prediction of a logistic or linear regression model (see [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/1149/40048) for details).

One solution to the multicollinearity of one-hot encoding is simply to, remove one of the values. With that, you don't loose information and, at the same time, you remove the multicollinearity. `drop_first=True` is precisely for that.

In cases where multicollinearity is not a problem, however, it is desirable to have all the dummies and therefore use `drop_first=False`. Nevertheless, it should be decided case by case. For instance, in decision trees, it's easier to learn the association between the dummy having value 1 than to learn that all the others have value 0. In the case of k nearest neighbours, having n - 1 dummies makes the distances between samples with the missing value different than distances between samples with the other values, so it would be best to have all the dummies (at least with the Euclidean distance).

Other cases where it's specifically better to have all dummies is the case where there are missing values and you are encoding them as all zeroes.

Finally, in models with regularization, it is also needed to keep all dummies because otherwise, the predictions may depend on which column you leave out (see [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/231285/40048)).

Comment: I understand why to use drop_first=True, I wanted to understand when the opposite would happen, that you would prefer drop_first=False.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the answer with that information.